# How to add a new button in tinymce

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, tinymce

I have solved my part to add a button almost.

```
    setup : function(ed) {
    // Add a custom button
    ed.addButton('Information', {
        title : 'Viktig Information',
        image : '../img/page_white_text.png',
        onclick : function() {
            // Add you own code to execute something on click
            ed.focus();
            ed.selection.setContent('Text here');
    }
    });
}
```

But now i wonder how i can make this to work like their bold button and stuff? So when i press the bold the text becomes bold..

I want the same with my button, when i press my button i want a div to appear. Anyone knows how i can do this?!

Comment: are you using tinymce 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy task to perform.
Just add something like this to your editor init function.
See this [page of moxycode](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.addButton) too.

```
tinyMCE.init({
  ...
  theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,..'

  setup: function(ed) {

      ed.onInit.add(function(ed) {
        // Scroll runter
        ed.addCommand('my_own_command', function() {
          alert('my_own_command called!');
        });
      });

      // Register example button
      ed.addButton('example', {
        title: 'example.desc',
        // make sure the image exists
        image: '../jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/example/img/example.gif',
        onclick: function() {
          ed.windowManager.alert('Hello world!!');
          // execute my_own_command
          ed.execCommand('my_own_command');
        }
      });
    }, // end setup
    ...
});
```

Comment: That part i already solved but i want it to be like bold text, so it adds <strong>Text</strong>

Comment: thx, for accepting my answer. in case you find an answer especialy helpfull you might even upvote such an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize TinyMCE you can specify which buttons are on which row.

Here is some documentation

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:theme_advanced_buttons_1_n

Comment: But i mean my own button. I want to make an own button my own function that works with tinymce